# How can I use cursor: Copy with event.preventDefault()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

I want to add a cursor : copy on my dropzone, but also I used event.preventDefault() dismiss the behavior when I drop a file, It is being open in the browser.
    A fragment of my react code :

```
const handleDragOver = (event: React.DragEvent<HTMLDivElement>): void => {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log("Drag Over")
};`
```

And the implementation on render:

```
return(<div
    id="drop-area"
    ref={this.dropRef}
    className= 'checklist-pane--is-dragging'
    onDragEnter={handleDragEnter}
    onDragLeave={handleDragLeave}
    onDragOver={handleDragOver}
    onDrop={handleDrop}
>)
```

The css :

```
&--is-dragging {
    border-color: $color-primary;
    background: rgba($color-primary, 0.2);
    cursor: copy;
}
```

Comment: what are you using? react-dnd?

Answer (score 0):

you could set a boolean in the component state on dragEnter that implies that you are currently hovering an element and set that boolean to false onDragLeave

```js
class YourComp extends React.Component {

   state = {
      isDragging: false,
   }

   handleDragEnter = (event) => {
      ...
      this.setState({ isDragging: true });
   }

   handleDragLeave = (event) => {
       this.setState({ isDragging: false });
   }



   render() {
      const { isDragging } = this.state;
      const className = isDragging ? checklist-pane--is-dragging' : '';
      return (<div
                    id="drop-area"
                    ref={this.dropRef}
                    className={className}
                    onDragEnter={this.handleDragEnter}
                    onDragLeave={this.handleDragLeave}
                    onDragOver={handleDragOver}
                    onDrop={handleDrop}
                >);
   }
}
```

Comment: I did just that, but it isn't work yet. The cursor only works when I delete the event.preventDefault function, but I need it